# Is there a way to alias/anchor an array in YAML?

Tags: yaml, assets

I'm using [Jammit](http://documentcloud.github.com/jammit/) to package assets up for a Rails application and I have a few asset files that I'd like to be included in each of a few groups. For example, I'd like [Sammy](http://github.com/quirkey/sammy) and its plugins to be in both my `mobile` and `screen` JS packages.

I've tried this:

```
sammy: &SAMMY
  - public/javascripts/vendor/sammy.js
  - public/javascripts/vendor/sammy*.js

mobile:
  <<: *SAMMY
  - public/javascripts/something_else.js
```

and this:

```
mobile:
  - *SAMMY
```

but both put the Sammy JS files in a nested Array, which Jammit can't understand. Is there a syntax for including the elements of an Array directly in another Array?

**NB**: I realize that in this case there are only two elements in the `SAMMY` Array, so it wouldn't be too bad to give each an alias and reference both in each package. That's fine for this case, but quickly gets unmaintainable when there are five or ten elements that have a specific load order.

Comment: Standard authors rejected this feature: https://github.com/yaml/yaml/issues/35

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Your example is valid YAML (a convenient place to check is [YPaste](http://ben-kiki.org/ypaste/)), but it's not defined what the merge does. Per the [spec](http://yaml.org/type/merge.html), a merge key can have a value:

1. A mapping, in which case it's merged into the parent mapping.
2. A sequence of mappings, in which case each is merged, one-by-one, into the parent mapping.

**There's no way of merging sequences on YAML level**.

You can, however, do this in code. Using the YAML from your second idea:

```
mobile:
  - *SAMMY
```

you'll get nested sequences - so flatten them! Assuming you have a mapping of such nested sequences:

```
data = YAML::load(File.open('test.yaml'))
data.each_pair { |key, value| value.flatten! }
```

(Of course, if you have a more complicated YAML file, and you don't want every sequence flattened (or they're not all sequences), you'll have to do some filtering.)

Comment: Here's an example: http://www.yaml.org/ypaste/803/index.html. I just checked again and noticed that it's not a syntax error; it's that this construct doesn't create a flat array; it creates a map, which Jammit can't handle. I just edited the question to show this.

Comment: @James, sorry, I didn't quite realize you were merging sequences. Edited.

Comment: Make sure you flatten(1) for a shallow flatten so you don't destroy your arrays in the values.

Answer (score 77):

Closest solution I know of is this one:

```
sammy:
  - &SAMMY1
    public/javascripts/vendor/sammy.js
  - &SAMMY2
    public/javascripts/vendor/sammy*.js

mobile:
  - *SAMMY1
  - *SAMMY2
  - public/javascripts/something_else.js
```

Alternatively, as already suggested, flatten the nested lists in a code snippet.

Note: according to [yaml-online-parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/), your first suggestion is not a valid use of << (used to merge keys from two dictionaries. The anchor then has to point to another dictionary I believe.

Comment: This won't work if sammy1/samm2 need multiple elements in them

Answer (score 47):

If you want `mobile` to be equal to `sammy`, you can just do:

```
mobile: *SAMMY
```

However if you want `mobile` to contain other elements in addition to those in `sammy`, there's no way to do that in YAML to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

**This solution is for Symfony/PHP only** (considerations for other languages, see below)

Note about array keys from the [PHP array manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> Strings containing valid decimal ints, unless the number is preceded by a + sign, will be cast to the int type. E.g. the key "8" will actually be stored under 8. [...]

This means that if you actually index your anchor array with integer keys, you can simply add new keys by continuing the initial list. So your solution would look like this:

```
sammy: &SAMMY
  1: public/javascripts/vendor/sammy.js
  2: public/javascripts/vendor/sammy*.js

mobile:
  <<: *SAMMY
  3: public/javascripts/something_else.js
```

You can even overwrite keys and still add new ones:

```
laptop:
  <<: *SAMMY
  1: public/javascripts/sammy_laptop.js
  3: public/javascripts/something_else.js
```

In both cases the end result is a perfectly valid indexed array, just like before.

---

**Other programming languages**

Depending on your YAML implementation *and* how you iterate over your array, this could conceivably also be used in other programming languages. Though with a caveat.

For instance, in JS you can access numerical string keys by their integer value as well:

```
const sammy = {"1": "public/javascripts/vendor/sammy.js"}

sammy["1"]; // "public/javascripts/vendor/sammy.js"
sammy[1]; // "public/javascripts/vendor/sammy.js"
```

But you'd need to keep in mind, **that your initial array is now an object**, and that you would need to iterate over it accordingly, e.g.:

```
Object.keys(sammy).forEach(key => console.log(sammy[key]))
```

Answer (score -4):

As it has been suggested, when you need to flatten a list, at least in ruby, it is trivial to add a "!flatten" type specifier to mobile and implement a class that extends Array, adds the yaml_tag and flattens the coder seq on init_with.