# Extend an array in YAML?

Tags: yaml

Suppose I have:

```
base_array:
  -1
  -2
```

how could I do something like:

```
my_array: << base_array
  -3
```

so that my_array was `[1,2,3]`

Update:  I should specify that I want the extending to occur inside the YAML itself.

Comment: @meagar: Yaml has the *, &, and << operators for references and merging.  You can extend a hash reference, why shouldnt you be able to extend an array reference?

Comment: Yes, I realized you were trying to extend a hash, rather than simply add additional data at arbitrary points.

Comment: I'm trying to extend an array, not a hash.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to alias/anchor an array in YAML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948933/is-there-a-way-to-alias-anchor-an-array-in-yaml)

Comment: looks like it is a dupe.. was hoping there'd be some sort of method to DRY up YAMLs in this regard but apparently not..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there YAML syntax for sharing part of a list or map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254178/is-there-yaml-syntax-for-sharing-part-of-a-list-or-map)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge YAML arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090177/how-to-merge-yaml-arrays)

Comment: Hope it helps - https://github.com/yaml/yaml/issues/35

Comment: Please also tell about your post-processing environment (e.g. java, python, etc.) and the concrete context (what content will your arrays contain, for which purpose). That may help finding  the best solution.

Comment: As a fallback, if the application code is also maintained by you, one can recursively merge them there, similar to how I did it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59832361/extract-set-of-leaf-values-found-in-nested-dicts-and-lists-excluding-none).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since the already commented [issue#35](https://github.com/yaml/yaml/issues/35) exists, **merge-keys** `<<` doesn't help you. It only merges/inserts referenced *keys* into a map (see YAML docs [merge](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html)). Instead you should work with **sequences** and use *anchor* `&` and *alias* `*`.

So your example should look like this:

```
base_list: &base
    - 1
    - 2

extended: &ext
    - 3

extended_list:
    [*base, *ext]
```

Will give result in output like this (JSON):

```
{
  "base_list": [
    1, 
    2
  ], 
  "extended": [
    3
  ], 
  "extended_list": [
    [
      1, 
      2
    ], 
    [
      3
    ]
  ]
}
```

Although **not exactly what you expected**, but maybe your parsing/loading environment can **flatten** the *nested array/list* to a simple array/list.

You can always test YAML online, for example use:

- [http://ben-kiki.org/ypaste](http://ben-kiki.org/ypaste/data/1109/index.html)
- [Online YAML Parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/)

Answer (score 2):

I needed to do the same thing but to run on Azure DevOps Pipeline. In particular, I had to update the [stage dependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#specify-dependencies) dynamically. How I did it:

```
dependents: [Stage_A, Stage_B]
otherDependents: [Stage_C] # This needed to be added by policy to the pipeline's execution
dependsOn:
- ${{ each dependent in dependents }}:
  - ${{ dependent }}
- ${{ each dependent in otherDependents }}:
  - ${{ dependent }}
```

Doing so resulted in the required setup:

```
dependents: [Stage_A, Stage_B]
otherDependents: [Stage_C] # This needed to be added by policy to the pipeline's execution
dependsOn:
  - Stage_A
  - Stage_B
  - Stage_C
```

I say dynamically because the variable `dependents` came from a template to which I had to append `Stage_C`.