# How to merge YAML arrays?

Tags: list, data-structures, yaml

I would like to merge arrays in YAML, and load them via ruby -

```
some_stuff: &some_stuff
 - a
 - b
 - c

combined_stuff:
  <<: *some_stuff
  - d
  - e
  - f
```

I'd like to have the combined array as `[a,b,c,d,e,f]`

I receive the error: did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping

How do I merge arrays in YAML?

Comment: @PatrickCollins I found this question trying to reduce duplication in my [.gitlab-ci.yml](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/) file and unfortunately I have no control over the parser that GitLab CI uses :(

Comment: As a fallback, if the application code is also maintained by you, one can recursively merge them there, similar to how I did it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59832361/extract-set-of-leaf-values-found-in-nested-dicts-and-lists-excluding-none).

Answer (score 91):

If the aim is to run a sequence of shell commands, you may be able to achieve this as follows:

```
# note: no dash before commands
some_stuff: &some_stuff |-
    a
    b
    c

combined_stuff:
  - *some_stuff
  - d
  - e
  - f
```

This is equivalent to:

```
some_stuff: "a\nb\nc"

combined_stuff:
  - "a\nb\nc"
  - d
  - e
  - f
```

I have been using this on my `gitlab-ci.yml` (to answer @rink.attendant.6 comment on the question).

---

Working example that we use to support `requirements.txt` having private repos from gitlab:

```
.pip_git: &pip_git
- git config --global url."https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.com".insteadOf "ssh://git@gitlab.com"
- mkdir -p ~/.ssh
- chmod 700 ~/.ssh
- echo "$SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
- chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts

test:
    image: python:3.7.3
    stage: test
    script:
        - *pip_git
        - pip install -q -r requirements_test.txt
        - python -m unittest discover tests

use the same `*pip_git` on e.g. build image...
```

where `requirements_test.txt` contains e.g.

`-e git+ssh://git@gitlab.com/example/example.git@v0.2.2#egg=example`

Comment: Clever. I'm using it in our Bitbucket pipeline now. Thanks

Comment: *The trailing dash is not required here, only the pipe at the end is enough.

*This is an inferior solution since when the job fails on a very long multi-line statement it's not clear which command failed.

Comment: @MinaLuke, inferior in comparison to what? None of the current answers provide a way to merge two items using only yaml... Moreover, there is nothing in the question stating that the OP wishes to use this in CI/CD. Finally, when this is used in CI/CD, logging only depends on the particular CI/CD used, not on the yaml declaration. So, if anything, the CI/CD that you are referring to is the one doing a bad job. The yaml in this answer is valid, and solves OP's problem.

Comment: @JorgeLeitao I guess you use it to combine Rules. Can you provide an working gitlabci example? I tried something based on your solution, but get always an validation error.

Comment: @niels, I have added an example with a working gitlabci example. Note that some IDEs mark this yaml as invalid, even though it is not.

Comment: the key for me here was using `- *stuff` and not `<<: *stuff`

Comment: it doesn't work for me. with - i get an error, like it trying to insert the list inside a list item. i dont know  how to use the pipe. what was it for? how @Dariop manage to use it in BB Pipelines?

Comment: Like @VictorFerreira mentioned, `- *pip_git` inserts a list in its place, so `script` would end up having `3` items, the first being a list of strings followed by `2` strings.

Comment: I'm suspicious about this. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but if it gets transformed to `"a\nb\nc"`, this would mean gitlab-runner won't get a chance to check exit codes of `a` and `b`. So if any command in the sequence except the last one has failed, this wouldn't interrupt pipeline and runner would continue executing the rest of the commands..

Comment: @JorgeLeitao Actually, your working example is a bit different (and better) then the actual answer ;)

Comment: You can use `extends` keyword in gitlab ci to merge various sections of a job. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#extends

Comment: @lead-free It seems like that is only for merging objects. In https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#use-extends-and-include-together it says "script does not merge, but script: ['rake rspec'] overwrites script: ['echo "Hello world!"']. You can use YAML anchors to merge arrays." So extends doesn't take care of this use case (or mine).

Answer (score 40):

This is not going to work:

1. merge is only supported by the YAML specifications for mappings and not for sequences
2. you are completely mixing things by having a merge key `<<`
   followed by the key/value separator `:` and a value that is a
   reference **and then continue with a list at the same indentation
   level**

This is not correct YAML:

```
combine_stuff:
  x: 1
  - a
  - b
```

So your example syntax would not even make sense as a YAML extension proposal.

If you want to do something like merging multiple arrays you might want to consider a syntax like:

```
combined_stuff:
  - <<: *s1, *s2
  - <<: *s3
  - d
  - e
  - f
```

where `s1`, `s2`, `s3` are anchors on sequences (not shown) that you
want to merge into a new sequence and then have the `d`, `e` and `f`
appended to that. But YAML is resolving these kind of structures depth
first, so there is no real context available during the processing
of the merge key. There is no array/list available to you where you
could attach the processed value (the anchored sequence) to.

You can take the approach as proposed by @dreftymac, but this has the huge disadvantage that you
somehow need to know which nested sequences to flatten (i.e. by knowing the "path" from the root
of the loaded data structure to the parent sequence), or that you recursively walk the loaded
data structure searching for nested arrays/lists and indiscriminately flatten all of them.

A better solution IMO would be to use tags to load data structures
that do the flattening for you. This allows for clearly denoting what
needs to be flattened and what not and gives you full control over
whether this flattening is done during loading, or done during
access. Which one to choose is a matter of ease of implementation and
efficiency in time and storage space. This is the same trade-off that needs to be made
for implementing the [merge *key* feature](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html) and
there is no single solution that is always the best.

E.g. my `ruamel.yaml` library uses the brute force merge-dicts during
loading when using its safe-loader, which results in merged
dictionaries that are normal Python dicts. This merging has to be done
up-front, and duplicates data (space inefficient) but is fast in value
lookup. When using the round-trip-loader, you want to be able to dump
the merges unmerged, so they need to be kept separate. The dict like
datastructure loaded as a result of round-trip-loading, is space
efficient but slower in access, as it needs to try and lookup a key
not found in the dict itself in the merges (and this is not cached, so
it needs to be done every time).  Of course such considerations are
not very important for relatively small configuration files.

---

The following implements a merge like scheme for lists in python using objects with tag `flatten`
which on-the-fly recurses into items which are lists and tagged `toflatten`. Using these two tags
you can have YAML file:

```
l1: &x1 !toflatten
  - 1 
  - 2
l2: &x2
  - 3 
  - 4
m1: !flatten
  - *x1
  - *x2
  - [5, 6]
  - !toflatten [7, 8]
```

(the use of flow vs block style sequences is completely arbitrary and has no influence on the
loaded result).

When iterating over the items that are the value for key `m1` this
"recurses" into the sequences tagged with `toflatten`, but displays
other lists (aliased or not) as a single item.

One possible way with Python code to achieve that is:

```python
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()


@yaml.register_class
class Flatten(list):
   yaml_tag = u'!flatten'
   def __init__(self, *args):
      self.items = args

   @classmethod
   def from_yaml(cls, constructor, node):
       x = cls(*constructor.construct_sequence(node, deep=True))
       return x

   def __iter__(self):
       for item in self.items:
           if isinstance(item, ToFlatten):
               for nested_item in item:
                   yield nested_item
           else:
               yield item


@yaml.register_class
class ToFlatten(list):
   yaml_tag = u'!toflatten'

   @classmethod
   def from_yaml(cls, constructor, node):
       x = cls(constructor.construct_sequence(node, deep=True))
       return x



data = yaml.load(Path('input.yaml'))
for item in data['m1']:
    print(item)
```

which outputs:

```
1
2
[3, 4]
[5, 6]
7
8
```

As you can see you can see, in the sequence that needs flattening, you
can either use an alias to a tagged sequence or you can use a tagged
sequence. YAML doesn't allow you to do:

```
- !flatten *x2
```

, i.e. tag an
anchored sequence, as this would essentially make it into a different
datastructure.

Using *explicit* tags is IMO better than having some magic going on as
with YAML merge keys `<<`. If nothing else you now have to go through
hoops if you happen to have a YAML file with a mapping that has a key
`<<` that you don't want to act like a merge key, e.g. when you make a
mapping of C operators to their descriptions in English (or some other natural language).

Comment: What is the meaning of: "merge is only supported by the YAML specifications for mappings and not for sequences"? https://yaml.org/type/merge.html suggests the opposite: "If the value associated with the merge key is a sequence, then this sequence is expected to contain mapping nodes and each of these nodes is merged in turn according to its order in the sequence." Is the distinction that YAML specifies merge for sequences, but only if they contain mapping nodes, not arbitrary sequences?

Answer (score 34):

### Update: 2019-07-01 14:06:12

- **Note**: another answer to this question was substantially edited with an [update on alternative approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30683699/42223).

  - That updated answer mentions an alternative to the workaround in this answer. It has been added to the **See also** section below.

### Context

This post assumes the following context:

- python 2.7
- python YAML parser

### Problem

lfender6445 wishes to merge two or more lists within a YAML file, and have those
merged lists appear as one singular list when parsed.

### Solution (Workaround)

This may be obtained simply by assigning YAML anchors to mappings, where the
desired lists appear as child elements of the mappings. There are caveats to this, however, (see "Pitfalls" infra).

In the example below we have three mappings (`list_one, list_two, list_three`) and three anchors
and aliases that refer to these mappings where appropriate.

When the YAML file is loaded in the program we get the list we want, but
it may require a little modification after load (see pitfalls below).

### Example

#### Original YAML file

```
  list_one: &id001
   - a
   - b
   - c

  list_two: &id002
   - e
   - f
   - g

  list_three: &id003
   - h
   - i
   - j

  list_combined:
      - *id001
      - *id002
      - *id003
```

#### Result after YAML.safe_load

```
## list_combined
  [
    [
      "a",
      "b",
      "c"
    ],
    [
      "e",
      "f",
      "g"
    ],
    [
      "h",
      "i",
      "j"
    ]
  ]
```

### Pitfalls

- this approach produces a nested list of lists, which may not be the exact desired output, but this can be post-processed using the *flatten* method
- the [usual caveats to YAML anchors and aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=yaml+anchors+and+aliases) apply for uniqueness and declaration order

### Conclusion

This approach allows creation of merged lists by use of the alias and anchor feature of YAML.

Although the output result is a nested list of lists, this can be easily transformed using the `flatten` method.

### See also

#### Updated alternative approach by @Anthon

- [See alternative approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30683699/42223)

#### Examples of the `flatten` method

- Javascript `flatten` ;; [Merge/flatten an array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript)
- Ruby `flatten` ;; http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-flatten
- Python `flatten` ;; https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/254676/23884

Answer (score 29):

If you only need to merge one item into a list you can do

```
fruit:
  - &banana
    name: banana
    colour: yellow

food:
  - *banana
  - name: carrot
    colour: orange
```

which yields

```
fruit:
  - name: banana
    colour: yellow

food:
  - name: banana
    colour: yellow
  - name: carrot
    colour: orange
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to enable merging arrays in python is by defining a `!flatten` tag.
(This uses PyYAML, unlike Anthon's answer above. This may be necessary in cases when you don't have control over which package is used in the back end, e.g., `anyconfig`).

```py
import yaml

yaml.add_constructor("!flatten", construct_flat_list)

def flatten_sequence(sequence: yaml.Node) -> Iterator[str]:
    """Flatten a nested sequence to a list of strings
        A nested structure is always a SequenceNode
    """
    if isinstance(sequence, yaml.ScalarNode):
        yield sequence.value
        return
    if not isinstance(sequence, yaml.SequenceNode):
        raise TypeError(f"'!flatten' can only flatten sequence nodes, not {sequence}")
    for el in sequence.value:
        if isinstance(el, yaml.SequenceNode):
            yield from flatten_sequence(el)
        elif isinstance(el, yaml.ScalarNode):
            yield el.value
        else:
            raise TypeError(f"'!flatten' can only take scalar nodes, not {el}")

def construct_flat_list(loader: yaml.Loader, node: yaml.Node) -> List[str]:
    """Make a flat list, should be used with '!flatten'

    Args:
        loader: Unused, but necessary to pass to `yaml.add_constructor`
        node: The passed node to flatten
    """
    return list(flatten_sequence(node))
```

This recursive flattening takes advantage of the PyYAML document structure, which parses all arrays as `SequenceNode`s, and all values as `ScalarNode`s.
The behavior can be tested (and modified) in the following test function.

```py
import pytest
def test_flatten_yaml():
    # single nest
    param_string = """
    bread: &bread
      - toast
      - loafs
    chicken: &chicken
      - *bread
    midnight_meal: !flatten
      - *chicken
      - *bread
    """
    params = yaml.load(param_string)
    assert sorted(params["midnight_meal"]) == sorted(
        ["toast", "loafs", "toast", "loafs"]
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can merge mappings then convert their keys into a list, under these conditions:

- if you are using jinja2 templating and
- if item order is not important

```
some_stuff: &some_stuff
 a:
 b:
 c:

combined_stuff:
  <<: *some_stuff
  d:
  e:
  f:

{{ combined_stuff | list }}
```

Comment: What's wrong with this answer? I don't mind downvotes if they are argumented. I'll keep the answer for people who can make use of it.

Comment: Likely because this answer relies on jinja2 templating, when the question asks to do it in yml. jinja2 requires a Python environment, which is counter-productive if the OP is trying to DRY. Also, many CI/CD tools do not accept a templating step.

Comment: Thanks @JorgeLeitao. That makes sense. I learned YAML and Jinja2 together while developing Ansible playbooks and templates and can't think about one without another

Comment: Well, I went there for ansible yaml as well; but what you did @sm4rk0 is not combining list, but hash (dictionnaries). And yes, it works, it's [even documented here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_advanced_syntax.html#yaml-anchors-and-aliases-sharing-variable-values) but unfortunatly, adding item to an existing list in an inventory file [seems to not be possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948933/is-there-a-way-to-alias-anchor-an-array-in-yaml)...