# Getting GitLab CI to clone private repositories

Tags: ssh, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have GitLab & GitLab CI set up to host and test some of my private repos. For my composer modules under this system, I have Satis set up to resolve my private packages.

Obviously these private packages require an ssh key to clone them, and I have this working in the terminal - I can run composer install and get these packages, so long as I have the key added with `ssh-add` in the shell.

However, when running my tests in GitLab CI, if a project has any of these dependencies the tests will not complete as my GitLab instance needs authentication to get the deps (obviously), and the test fails saying `Host key verification failed`.

My question is how do I set this up so that when the runner runs the test it can authenticate to gitlab without a password? I have tried putting a password-less ssh-key in my runners `~/.ssh` folder, however the build wont even add the key, "eval `ssh-agent -s`" followed by ssh-add seems to fail saying the agent isn't running...

Comment: As of 2017, the highest-ranked answer is out-of-date. [Marco's answer using `GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42224451/119527) is correct. I added this feature specifically to avoid the mess of dealing with injecting SSH keys.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart But isn't this solution a securty issue? I could clone any private GitLab repository as long as I know the relative URL? The runner could zip the cloned content and send it via email.

Comment: @Paebbels No it is not an issue. As of GitLab 8.12, CI jobs run [as the user that triggered the pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/new_ci_build_permissions_model.html), with a token that has a reduced set of privileges. The CI job can only access the same repositories as the person who pushed the code.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'm posting this as an answer since others weren't completely clear and/or detailed IMHO

Starting from GitLab 8.12+, assuming the submodule repo is in the same server as the one requesting it, you can now:

1. Set up the repo with git submodules as usual (`git submodule add git@somewhere:folder/mysubmodule.git`)
2. Modify your `.gitmodules` file as follows

   ```
    [submodule "mysubmodule"]
      path = mysubmodule
      url = ../../group/mysubmodule.git
   ```

   where `../../group/mysubmodule.git` is a relative path from your repository to the submodule's one.
3. Add the following lines to `gitlab-ci.yml`

   ```
    variables:
      GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
   ```

   to instruct the runner to fetch all submodules **before** the build.

Caveat: if your runner seems to ignore the `GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY` directive, you should probably consider [updating it](https://easyengine.io/tutorials/gitlab/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/#update).

(source: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/git_submodules.html)

Comment: I don't favour this approach because I don't think Gitlab should be forcing me to configure submodules in a specific way. I prefer to [use Gitlab tokens and keep the configuration in `.gitlab-ci.yml`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53758544/474189).

Comment: Does this solution work if you want to run `git submodule update --init --recursive` locally?

Comment: In particular, how can one use this `.gitmodules`and `.gitlab-ci.yml` file to run `gitlab-runner` locally?

Comment: It doesn’t work for repositories on another server, that cannot have a relative path.

Comment: @Gus Yes if you locally run `git submodule update --recursive --remote` it works. In my case all my submodules are in gitlab under same group though.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work anymore, at least not with `gitlab-runner` **13.3.1**. The runner does seem to use that relative path poorly (ie, from the current directory the command is ran from instead of from the repository url).

Comment: In case the sumodule origin project in Gitlab is private, you need to add the a username and a username's access token to the URL in the .gitmodules file in order for the update to succeed: `url = https://<username>:<access_token>@gitlab/../group/mysubmodule.git`

Answer (score 55):

See also other solutions:

- git submodule permission (see [Marco A.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42224451/831180))
- job token and override repo in git config (see [a544jh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49552383/831180))

---

Here a full howto with SSH keys:

### General Design

- generating a pair of SSH keys
- adding the private one as a secure environment variable of your project
- making the private one available to your test scripts on GitLab-CI
- adding the public one as a deploy key on each of your private dependencies

### Generating a pair of public and private SSH keys

Generate a pair of public and private SSH keys without passphrase:

```
ssh-keygen -b 4096 -C "<name of your project>" -N "" -f /tmp/name_of_your_project.key
```

### Adding the private SSH key to your project

You need to add the key as a secure environment variable to your project as
following:

- browse `https://<gitlab_host>/<group>/<project_name>/variables`
- click on "Add a variable"
- fill the text field `Key` with `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY`
- fill the text field `Value` with the private SSH key itself
- click on "Save changes"

### Exposing the private SSH key to your test scripts

In order to make your private key available to your test scripts you need to add
the following to your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
before_script:
  # install ssh-agent
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
  # run ssh-agent
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  # add ssh key stored in SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable to the agent store
  - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
  # disable host key checking (NOTE: makes you susceptible to man-in-the-middle attacks)
  # WARNING: use only in docker container, if you use it with shell you will overwrite your user's ssh config
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
```

[Code Snippet comes from GitLab documentation](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc//ci/ssh_keys/README.md)

### Adding the public SSH key as a deploy key to all your private dependencies

You need to register the public SSH key as deploy key to all your private
dependencies as following:

- browse `https://<gitlab_host>/<group>/<dependency_name>/deploy_keys`
- click on "New deploy key"
- fill the text field `Title` with the name of your project
- fill the text field `Key` with the public SSH key itself
- click on "Create deploy key"

Comment: @Ridermansb Thanks for the link. The answer comes from a personal doc. I forgot the origin of the code snippet. It is worth to mention it. Thanks again for having pointed out.

Comment: Instead of echoing to disable StrictHostKeyChecking (and risking accidentally clobbering a real system's ssh config), add a gitlab CI variable like KNOWN_HOSTS that has the known host(s). See this for details: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/#verifying-the-ssh-host-keys

Comment: Can I use a name other than `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY`?

Comment: becko, you can change the name of the var SSH_PRIVATE_KEY. If you do, be sure to update it everywhere.

Comment: Security warning: That documentation doesn't use a passphrase on the private key.

Answer (score 51):

If you don't want to fiddle around with ssh keys or submodules, you can override the repo in git's configuration to authenticate with the job token instead (in `gitlab-ci.yml`):

```
before_script:
  - git config --global url."https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.example.com/group/repo.git".insteadOf git@gitlab.example.com:group/repo.git
```

Comment: I have encountered a problem with this - the git config global persists on next jobs on my runner. It completely breaks the CI. Have you had this problem? I can not clone any resources from my gitlab because the `CI_JOB_TOKEN` is stale.

Comment: @Darkowic I use the Docker runner so I haven't encountered that problem.

Comment: Me too. Though I solved it today :) Its because of npm... By default `npm install` modifies `package-lock.json`. When you set in your CI to only fetch changes instead of cloning, this modified `packge-lock.json` file persists between jobs and npm cannot install anything...

Comment: This solution is the most elegant. It works with dockerized GitLab Community Edition 11.6.4

Comment: You can also omit the group and repo to use the job token for all repos on the gitlab instance. See https://gist.github.com/Kovrinic/ea5e7123ab5c97d451804ea222ecd78a

Comment: please make sure you replace the colon on `git@gitlab.com:group/repo` to `gitlab.com/group/repo`. took me a while.

Comment: Why and how does GitLab allows `CI_JOB_TOKEN` to authenticate to a private repo? How does it know that given repo shouldnt be hidden but accessible to the repo where the CI is running?

Answer (score 27):

The [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42224451/474189) embeds Gitlab-specific requirements into my `.gitmodules` file. This forces a specific directory layout for local development and would complicate moving to another version control platform.

Instead, I followed the advice in [Juddling's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51227930/474189). Here's a more complete answer.

My `.gitmodules` files has the following contents:

```
[submodule "myproject"]
    url = git@git.myhost.com:mygroup/myproject.git
```

In my `gitlab-ci.yml` I have the following:

```
build:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - git config --global url."https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@git.myhost.com/".insteadOf "git@git.myhost.com:"
    - git submodule sync && git submodule update --init
```

The trailing `/` and `:` are critical in the `git config` line, since we are mapping from SSH authentication to HTTPS. This tripped me up for a while with "*Illegal port number*" errors.

I like this solution because it embeds the Gitlab-specific requirements in a Gitlab-specific file, which is ignored by everything else.

Comment: To save someone else from making the same silly pattern-matching mistake, for projects hosted on gitlab.com, `git config --global url."https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.com/".insteadOf "git@gitlab.com:"`

Comment: @Gus, can you post a working example of a ci config file? I posted a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58040183/can-anyone-post-a-working-example-of-gitlab-ci-that-has-external-submodules but can’t make this work at all

Answer (score 8):

I used [deploy tokens](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_tokens/#git-clone-a-repository) to solve this issue, as setting up SSH keys for a test runner  seems a little long winded.

```
git clone http://<username>:<deploy_token>@gitlab.example.com/tanuki/awesome_project.git
```

The deploy tokens are per project and are read only.

Answer (score 4):

One way to solve this without changing the git repository's structure is to perform the following steps:

### 1. get ssh host keys

Get the ssh host keys of the server that you are running on. For `gitlab.com`:

1. run `ssh-keyscan gitlab.com > known_hosts`
2. check that `ssh-keygen -lf known_hosts` agrees with the fingerprints reported  [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/gitlab_com/#ssh-host-keys-fingerprints).
3. copy the content of the `known_hosts` and paste it on a variable called `SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS` on the repository.

This step is only needed once.

### 2. configure the job to use ssh

```
before_script:
    - git config --global url."https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.com".insteadOf "git@gitlab.com:"
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - echo "$SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

The `"ssh://git@gitlab.com"` bit may be different if you are trying to do `git clone git@gitlab.com:` or `pip install -e git+ssh://git@gitlab.com/...`; adjust it accordingly to your needs.

At this point, your CI is able to use ssh to fetch from another (private) repository.

### 3. [Bonus DRY]

Use [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57209078/931303) to write it generically:

```
.enable_ssh: &enable_ssh |-
    git config --global url."https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.com".insteadOf "ssh://git@gitlab.com"
    mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    echo "$SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

and enable it on jobs that need it

```
test:
    stage: test
    before_script:
        - *enable_ssh
    script:
        - ...
```

Comment: the [3] worked for me when I needed to get private repositories using gitlab and `go get`

in particular the 
`git config --global url."https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.com".insteadOf "https://gitlab.com"`
(it's a bit modified)

Answer (score 2):

1. If your CI runner is running on a container model, you need to use the deploy key.  doc:  https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_tokens/#git-clone-a-repository

```sh
git clone https://<username>:<deploy_token>@gitlab.example.com/tanuki/awesome_project.git
```

2. Create your deploy token
3. Add your token in CI pipeline Variable
4. make sure your container has the git and change the git URL by insteadOf

```yaml
  image: docker:latest
  before_script:
    - apk add --no-cache curl jq python3 py3-pip git
    - git config --global url."https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.example.come/".insteadOf 'git@gitlab.example.come:'
```

for replace URL: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/working_with_projects.html#authenticate-git-fetches

Answer (score 1):

I had a scenario where I had to use my ssh key in 3 different scripts, so I put the ssh key stuff in a single shell script and called it first, before the other 3 scripts. This ended up not working, I think due to the `ssh-agent` not persisting between shell scripts, or something to that effect.  I ended up actually just outputting the private key into the `~/.ssh/id_rsa` file, which will for sure persist to other scripts.

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
script:
    - ci/init_ssh.sh
    - git push # or whatever you need ssh for
```

ci/init_ssh.sh

```
# only run in docker:
[[ ! -e /.dockerenv ]] && exit 0

mkdir -p ~/.ssh
echo "$GITLAB_RUNNER_SSH_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > /.ssh/config
```

It works like a charm!

Comment: Hi @user3246077! Thank you so much for the answer. I found a mistake, in the last line the `~` symbol to reference the user's home is missing. Can you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an alpine-based image (maybe `docker:latest` or `docker:dind`), your `before_script` might look like this:

```
before_script:
    - apk add --no-cache openssh-client git
    - mkdir -p /.ssh && touch /.ssh/known_hosts
    - ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> /.ssh/known_hosts
    - echo $SSH_KEY | base64 -d >> /.ssh/id_rsa && chmod 600 /.ssh/id_rsa
    - git clone git@git.myhost.com:mygroup/myproject.git
```

Answer (score 1):

Gitlab 15.9.0 introduces an update to the pre-defined variable `CI_JOB_TOKEN`. Now you can control other projects' access to your private repository, see the [release note](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/02/22/gitlab-15-9-released/#control-which-projects-can-access-your-project-with-a-cicd-job-token) and [documentation](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/02/22/gitlab-15-9-released/#control-which-projects-can-access-your-project-with-a-cicd-job-token).

Once access is granted, you can clone private repositories by adding this line to your job's `scripts` or `before_scripts`.

```bash
git clone https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.example.com/<namespace>/<project>
```

Unfortunately, this still does not play nicely with the [submodule integration with Gitlab CI/CD](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/git_submodules.html). Instead, I do this in my projects.

```yaml
# .gitlab-ci.yml
default:
  before_script:
  - git config --global url."https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.example.com/<namespace>/<project>.git".insteadOf 'git@gitlab.example.com/<namespace>/<project>.git'
  - git submodule update --init --recursive
```

or like this

```yaml
# .gitlab-ci.yml
default:
  before_script:
  - |
    cat << EOF > ~/.gitconfig
    [url "https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.example.com/<namespace>/<project>.git"]
        insteadOf = git@gitlab.example.com/<namespace>/<project>.git
    EOF
  - git submodule update --init --recursive
```

And this is what my `.gitmodules` would look like

```ini
[submodule "my-submodule"]
    path = modules/<project>
    url = git@gitlab.example.com/<namespace>/<project>.git
    branch = main
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to .gitlab-ci.yml did the trick for me. 
(as mentioned here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/new_ci_build_permissions_model.html#dependent-repositories)

```
before_script:
    echo -e "machine gitlab.com\nlogin gitlab-ci-token\npassword ${CI_JOB_TOKEN}" > ~/.netrc
```

(I tried setting up SSH_PRIVATE_KEY as mentioned in one of the answers above, it won't work)

Answer (score 0):

A variant of [Duncan Jones' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42224451/1720199) worked for me, the difference is that my modules are using HTTPS, like so:

```
[submodule "some-submodule"]
    path = submoduleDir
    url = https://gitlab.com/project-name/some-dir/submodule-app.git
```

Therfore I had to rewrite the domain `gitlab.com` to the domain + login/password: `gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.com`, which gives:

```
build:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - apk update && apk add git # I had install git (using docker in docker)
    - git config --global url."gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.com".insteadOf "gitlab.com"
    - git submodule sync && git submodule update --init
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems there is finally a [reasonable solution](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/new_ci_build_permissions_model.html#sts=Git%20submodules%20%C2%B6).

In short as of GitLab 8.12 all you need to do is use relative paths in the `.submodules`, and the `git submodule update --init` will simply work

Comment: This is an incomplete version of Marco A's answer above.