# ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY") is giving an error on gitlab-ci

Tags: bash, gitlab-ci

In gitlab, I made a variable `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` with my private key, and try to add it on the fly with

```
   before_script:
     - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
```

I get an error

```
/bin/sh: eval: line 81: syntax error: unexpected "("
```

How should I fix it ?

Comment: Why don't you just create a file with the private key, like `ssh-add` expects?

Comment: I am following this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/38570269/1956558

Comment: The immediate issue is that process substitution (`<(...)`) isn't supported by the POSIX shell specification, and whatever shell your system is actually using to execute the before-script doesn't either. Likely, your `/bin/sh` is something like `dash` rather than `bash`. You need to find someway to change what shell GitLab uses.

Comment: Even if `/bin/sh` *is* Bash, it'll run in POSIX mode if called as `/bin/sh` and choke on process substitution.

Comment: @chepner I am using alpine docker image.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I can never remember which non-POSIX features `bash` will still support even when invoked as `sh`.

Comment: @chepner The [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode) lists just two behaviours that Bash doesn't implement even when in POSIX, but it's not explicit about what extensions are still enabled.

Answer (score 0):

`echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | ssh-add -`

try this