# Download another private repository from gitlab CI with same author

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, docker-image

I have two GitLab repository, both of them are under my username in GitLab. Both of them are private. One repository is a dependency of the other, but the latter one don't use submodule. Instead, it install the package to the docker image.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25689231/getting-gitlab-ci-to-clone-private-repositories). But, I don't want to configure any token or other complex thing.

Is there any easy and friendly way to make my private repo transparent to myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `CI_JOB_TOKEN`, It is one the [predefined environment variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) of GitLab CI/CD which can be used without any specification needed. Base on [official documents](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) `CI_JOB_TOKEN` is described as follows:

> Token used for authenticating with the GitLab Container Registry and downloading dependent repositories

And base on this [document](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/new_ci_build_permissions_model.html#dependent-repositories):

> The Job environment variable `CI_JOB_TOKEN` can be used to authenticate any clones of dependent repositories. For example:
>
> ```
> git clone https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.com/<user>/<mydependentrepo>.git
> ```

So you can clone your dependent repository into the current pipeline by using above code in the script part of every job you want in `gitlab-ci.yml` file.
 **It works fine whether it uses `CI_JOB_TOKEN` instead of your password or any tokens and there is no need to worry about `gitlab-ci-token` in the URL. You can also put every desired user name instead of it.**