# Terragrunt/-form clone in Gitlab pipeline when using git::ssh://git@ for module source

Tags: authentication, terraform, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, terragrunt

I have a pipeline where I want to run terragrunt. I so far run everything local and use ssh to authenticate against Gitlab. Therefore, in my Terraform modules, I also use a git::ssh URL like below.

```
module "data_org" {
  source = "git::ssh://git@git.foobar.de/bar/xdf/terraform_modules.git//modules/data_org?ref=develop"
}
```

Now, I do not know how to port this to a Gitlab pipeline. I would prefer using short-lived pipeline credentials like the Gitlab job token, but do not know how to make use of it. Did anybody know how to use this with Terraform?

What I come across already:

- [Gitlab job token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/ci_job_token.html#add-a-project-to-the-job-token-scope-allowlist)
- [Gitlab types of authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47471056/227821)
- [Gitlab job token for git clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25689231/getting-gitlab-ci-to-clone-private-repositories/49552383#49552383)

**Update 2023-10-26 https:** I tested `git config --global url.https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@git.foobar.de.insteadOf ssh://git@git.foobar.de` and got a bit further. Now I get the error "not found" for the repository, and I assume the problem is the `.git` suffix at the end. I do not know how to get rid of it yet but hope this is solvable.

Comment: Have you looked at using [secrets](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/secrets/)?

Comment: I haven't tried with SSH but with HTTPS [this](https://wahlnetwork.com/2020/08/11/using-private-git-repositories-as-terraform-modules/) seems to be a plausible solution..
You could add a stage before `terraform init` to update the `~/.gitconfig` file..

Comment: TO lxop secrets for git may be an option but rather complex. This would be my last resort. TO harashavmb if this works with job tokens, this would be wonderful. I try it out later in the day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credits to @harshavmb from the comment above for his recommendation of `insteadOf` which solved the problem.

The solution was twofold

- a) Using `git config --global url.https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@git.foobar.de.insteadOf ssh://git@git.foobar.de` so my ssh URL was rewritten to an HTTP one using the Gitlab job token to authenticate.
- b) [Allow access](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/ci_job_token.html#allow-access-to-your-project-with-a-job-token) needs to happen from the target repos side. Meaning I want to clone repo A but my pipeline and the job token is in repo B. To allow access I have to allow access in repo A so B can "access" it. The settings are under Settings->CI/CD->Token Access.

Comment: Hey Lony I think you could accept your own answer, it fits perfectly. Maybe also add a reference to @harshavamb links as it explains that .insteadOf is required and a reserved world for the command. I was a bit in doubt if insteadOf was a mistake, example or part of the command and had to go check his link to make sure.

Comment: Did so and hope it helps other readers as well. Thanks for your feedback!