# YAML Merge single sequence and deserialize with SnakeYAML JAVA

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I'm trying to merge sequence values with YAML to after deserialize with SnakeYAML with JAVA.

I expected this results:

```
{
  "root": {
    "seq4": [
      "001", 
      "002",
      "003"
    ], 
    "seq3": [
      "001", 
      "002",
      "003"
    ], 
    "seq2": [
      "001", 
      "002"
    ], 
    "seq1": [
      "001", 
      "002"
    ]
  }
}
```

But this is not possible for me with this YAML example:

```
root: 
  seq1: &seq1
    - '001' #first
    - '002' #secod
  seq2: *seq1
  seq3: &seq3
    *seq1
    - '003' #third
  seq4: *seq3
```

This example return the message:

while parsing a block mapping
  in "", line 2, column 3:
      seq1: &anch1
      ^
expected , but found ''
  in "", line 7, column 5:
        *anch1
        ^

[example](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=root%3A%20%0A%20%20seq1%3A%20%26anch1%0A%20%20%20%20-%20%27001%27%20%23first%0A%20%20%20%20-%20%27002%27%20%23secod%0A%20%20seq2%3A%20%2Aanch1%0A%20%20seq3%3A%20%26anch2%0A%20%20%20%20%2Aanch1%0A%20%20%20%20-%20%27003%27%20%23third%0A%20%20seq4%3A%20%2Aanch2&type=json)

Also, I probe this YAML definition but its return error to:

```
root: 
  seq1: &anch1
    - '001' #first
    - '002' #secod
  seq2: *anch1
  seq3: &anch2
    <<: *anch1
    - '003' #third
  seq4: *anch2
```

Any idea?? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Found this: [Github issue](https://github.com/yaml/yaml/issues/35). So your scenario would not be possible...

Also look at this question regarding merging of YAML arrays: [How to merge YAML arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090177/how-to-merge-yaml-arrays)

A workaround is to assign unique keys to the values, like so:

```
root: 
  seq1: &anch1
    1: '001' #first
    2: '002' #secod
  seq2: *anch1
  seq3: &anch2
    <<: *anch1
    3: '003' #third
  seq4: *anch2
```

This will yield:

```
"root": {
  "seq3": {
    "1": "001", 
    "2": "002", 
    "3": "003"
  }, 
  "seq2": {
    "1": "001", 
    "2": "002"
  }, 
  "seq1": {
    "1": "001", 
    "2": "002"
  }, 
  "seq4": {
    "1": "001", 
    "2": "002", 
    "3": "003"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But I like to merge arrays no a complex type.

Answer (score 1):

In YAML there is no language independent sequence element like there is language independent [merge key](http://Merge%20Key%20Language-Independent%20Type%20for%20YAML) for mappings.

One of the reasons for that is that you could still use the merge key (`<<`) without special meaning if the value is not a mapping.

You can of course do something like:

```
root: 
  seq1: &seq1
    - '001' #first
    - '002' #secod
  seq2: *seq1
  seq3: !CombineSequences &seq3
    - *seq1
    - ['003'] #third
  seq4: *seq3
```

And have a special type `CombineSequences` that combines its elements into one large list/array.