# How to set required partially only on some enum values in swagger?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I did not find the solution in the documentation, this is my yaml object:

```
type: object
properties:
attrKey:
   $ref: '../schemas/MyEnum.yaml'
required:
 - attrKey
```

MyEnum.yaml:

```
type: string
enum:
  - A
  - B
  - C
  - D
```

How to make for example only C value from enum as not required but use only this one enum, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? -- [Reusing a subset of an enum in OpenAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57507396/113116)

Comment: It is an interesting solution, but not answering a question, as I asked to not use 2 enums but one. It seems it is not possible to do it in swagger for now...