# Using global environment variables in Woodpecker CI

Tags: gitlab-ci, woodpecker-ci

I'm migrating from `GitLab CI` to `Woodpecker CI`. The current pipeline is defined as:

```yaml
default:
  cache:
    key: $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    paths:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/repository/
  image: docker.io/library/eclipse-temurin:8-jdk-focal

stages:
  - compile

variables:
  MAVEN_CONFIG: --batch-mode --no-transfer-progress
  MAVEN_OPTS: -Dmaven.repo.local=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/repository/

compile:
  stage: compile
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
  script:
    - ./mvnw compile $MAVEN_EXTRA_OPTS
  variables:
    MAVEN_EXTRA_OPTS: -DskipTests=true
```

I'm trying to find a way to declare `MAVEN_CONFIG` and `MAVEN_OPTS` in the same way they are exposed (read: globally for all steps) in `GitLab CI`, but I so far I haven't found a solution. I'm basically declaring them all over again in subsequent steps.

Is this functionality available and I missed it, or isn't yet implemented?

Comment: Update your post to include your current `.woodpecker.yml`, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `.woodpecker.yml` file defining a pipeline with steps. See, [Woodpecker CI: Intro](https://woodpecker-ci.org/docs/intro).

```yaml
# .woodpecker.yml
pipeline:
  build:
    image: debian
    commands:
      - echo "This is the build step"
  a-test-step:
    image: debian
    commands:
      - echo "Testing.."
```

To set environment variables, use the `environment` key. See, [Woodpecker CI: Environment Variables](https://woodpecker-ci.org/docs/usage/environment).

```yaml
pipeline:
  build:
    image: golang
    environment:
      # set environment variables
      - CGO=0
      - GOOS=linux
      - GOARCH=amd64
    commands:
      # expand/resolve environment variables by exporting
      - export PATH=$PATH:/go
      - go build
      - go test
```

Environment variables can be set globally for all builds via the `WOODPECKER_ENVIRONMENT` variable. See, [Woodpecker CI: Global Env Vars](https://woodpecker-ci.org/docs/usage/environment#global-environment-variables).

You *should* be able to share commands between steps with yaml anchors and aliases, as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57209078/2675670).

```yaml
.set-maven-env-vars: &set-maven-env-vars
  - export MAVEN_CONFIG="--batch-mode --no-transfer-progress"
  - export MAVEN_OPTS="-Dmaven.repo.local=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/repository/"

pipeline:
  build:
    image: golang
    commands:
      - *set-maven-env-vars
      - go build
      - go test
```

Comment: I don't have access to the instance, but regardless, I was leaning towards the solution about "having global variables within the pipeline". On GitHub they proposed to use aliases, but somehow I think having a dedicated key for this is better. So far, looks like it's not possible to declare them in the same way one would do in `GitLab CI`.

Comment: You're right. You can't set env vars globally in a `.woodpecker.yml` like you can in a `.gitlab.yml`. Let me know if that last example works for you or not.

Comment: What does the dot in `.set-maven-env-vars` mean? How does Woodpecker interpret this code fragment before `pipeline`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090177/how-to-merge-yaml-arrays/57209078#57209078