# Extract set of leaf values found in nested dicts and lists excluding None

Tags: python, recursion, nested, flatten

I have a nested structure read from YAML which is composed of nested lists and/or nested dicts or a mix of both at various levels of nesting. It can be assumed that the structure doesn't contain any recursive objects.

How do I extract from it the leaf values only? Also, I don't want any `None` value. The leaf values contain strings which is all I care for. It's okay for recursion to be used, considering that the maximum depth of the structure is not large enough to exceed stack recursion limits. A generator would optionally also be fine.

There exist similar questions which deal with flattening lists or dicts, but not a mix of both. Alternatively, if flattening a dict, they also return the flattened keys which I don't really need, and risk name conflicts.

I tried [`more_itertools.collapse`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.collapse) but its examples only show it to work with nested lists, and not with a mix of dicts and lists.

### Sample inputs

```py
struct1 = {
    "k0": None,
    "k1": "v1",
    "k2": ["v0", None, "v1"],
    "k3": ["v0", ["v1", "v2", None, ["v3"], ["v4", "v5"], []]],
    "k4": {"k0": None},
    "k5": {"k1": {"k2": {"k3": "v3", "k4": "v6"}, "k4": {}}},
    "k6": [{}, {"k1": "v7"}, {"k2": "v8", "k3": "v9", "k4": {"k5": {"k6": "v10"}, "k7": {}}}],
    "k7": {
        "k0": [],
        "k1": ["v11"],
        "k2": ["v12", "v13"],
        "k3": ["v14", ["v15"]],
        "k4": [["v16"], ["v17"]],
        "k5": ["v18", ["v19", "v20", ["v21", "v22", []]]],
    },
}

struct2 = ["aa", "bb", "cc", ["dd", "ee", ["ff", "gg"], None, []]]
```

### Expected outputs

```py
struct1_leaves = {f"v{i}" for i in range(23)}
struct2_leaves = {f"{s}{s}" for s in "abcdefg"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an adaption of the [reference answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59832362/) to use an inner function and a single `set`. It also uses recursion to produce the expected outputs for the sample inputs included in the question. It avoids passing every leaf through the entire call stack.

```py
from typing import Any, Set


def leaves(struct: Any) -> Set[Any]:
    """Return a set of leaf values found in nested dicts and lists excluding None values."""
    # Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59832594/
    values = set()

    def add_leaves(struct_: Any) -> None:
        if isinstance(struct_, dict):
            for sub_struct in struct_.values():
                add_leaves(sub_struct)
        elif isinstance(struct_, list):
            for sub_struct in struct_:
                add_leaves(sub_struct)
        elif struct_ is not None:
            values.add(struct_)

    add_leaves(struct)
    return values
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to use a generator with recursion:

```
struct1 = {'k0': None, 'k1': 'v1', 'k2': ['v0', None, 'v1'], 'k3': ['v0', ['v1', 'v2', None, ['v3'], ['v4', 'v5'], []]], 'k4': {'k0': None}, 'k5': {'k1': {'k2': {'k3': 'v3', 'k4': 'v6'}, 'k4': {}}}, 'k6': [{}, {'k1': 'v7'}, {'k2': 'v8', 'k3': 'v9', 'k4': {'k5': {'k6': 'v10'}, 'k7': {}}}], 'k7': {'k0': [], 'k1': ['v11'], 'k2': ['v12', 'v13'], 'k3': ['v14', ['v15']], 'k4': [['v16'], ['v17']], 'k5': ['v18', ['v19', 'v20', ['v21', 'v22', []]]]}}
def flatten(d):
   for i in getattr(d, 'values', lambda :d)():
      if isinstance(i, str):
         yield i
      elif i is not None:
         yield from flatten(i)

print(set(flatten(struct1)))
```

Output:

```
{'v10', 'v9', 'v8', 'v7', 'v0', 'v18', 'v16', 'v1', 'v21', 'v11', 'v14', 'v15', 'v12', 'v13', 'v4', 'v2', 'v5', 'v20', 'v6', 'v19', 'v3', 'v22', 'v17'}
```

---

```
struct2 = ["aa", "bb", "cc", ["dd", "ee", ["ff", "gg"], None, []]]
print(set(flatten(struct2)))
```

Output:

```
{'cc', 'ff', 'dd', 'gg', 'bb', 'ee', 'aa'}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a straightforward reference solution which uses recursion to produce the expected outputs for the sample inputs included in the question.

```py
from typing import Any, Set


def leaves(struct: Any) -> Set[Any]:
    """Return a set of leaf values found in nested dicts and lists excluding None values."""
    # Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59832362/
    values = set()
    if isinstance(struct, dict):
        for sub_struct in struct.values():
            values.update(leaves(sub_struct))
    elif isinstance(struct, list):
        for sub_struct in struct:
            values.update(leaves(sub_struct))
    elif struct is not None:
        values.add(struct)
    return values
```

Comment: Seems inefficient to pass every leaf through the entire call stack, updating it into sets over and over again.

Comment: You could have a recursive inner function that doesn't return anything but adds everything to the set held by the outer function (non-recursive, just calls the inner).