# Re-using environment variables in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

Is it possible to re-use environment variables that are shared among multiple containers?

The idea is to avoid duplication, as illustrated in this example:

```yaml
version: '2'

services:

  db:
    image: example/db
    ports:
      - "8443:8443" 
    container_name: db
    hostname: db
    environment:
      - USER_NAME = admin 
      - USER_PASSWORD = admin 

svc:
  image: example/svc
  depends_on:
    - db
  ports:
    - "9443:9443"
  container_name: svc
  hostname: svc
  environment:
    - DB_URL = https://db:8443
    - DB_USER_NAME = admin
    - DB_USER_PASSWORD = admin
```

Answer (score 264, accepted):

The `extends` option can be nice but it's [not supported](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#extending-services) in `3.x` compose files. Other ways to go are:

1. [Extension fields](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#extension) (compose file 3.4+)

   If you can use 3.4+ compose files, extension fields are probably the best option:

   **docker-compose.yml**

   ```
    version: '3.4'

    x-common-variables: &common-variables
      VARIABLE: some_value
      ANOTHER_VARIABLE: another_value

    services:
      some_service:
        image: someimage
        environment: *common-variables

      another_service:
        image: anotherimage
        environment:
          <<: *common-variables
          NON_COMMON_VARIABLE: 'non_common_value'
   ```
2. [env_file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env_file-configuration-option) directive

   **docker-compose.yml**

   ```
    version: '3.2'

    services:
      some_service:
        image: someimage
        env_file:
          - 'variables.env'

      another_service:
        image: anotherimage
        env_file:
          - 'variables.env'
   ```

   **variables.env**

   ```
    VARIABLE=some_value
    ANOTHER_VARIABLE=another_value
   ```
3. **.env** [file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file) in project root
   (or variables at actual compose environment)

   Variables from .env file can be referenced in service configuration:

   **docker-compose.yml**

   ```
    version: '3.2'

    services:
      some_service:
        image: someimage
        environment:
          - VARIABLE

      another_service:
        image: anotherimage
        environment:
          - VARIABLE
          - ANOTHER_VARIABLE
   ```

   **.env**

   ```
    VARIABLE=some_value
    ANOTHER_VARIABLE=another_value
   ```

Comment: For those not too familiar with YAML: see "Merge key language" in YAML as to the reason for the notation==>     environment: <<: *common-variables. Basically &foo means "foo will be a reused variable", *foo denotes the reuse of a vars, and <<: inserts the variable mapping that follows into the current key. I'd edit but So says edit queue is full for some reason.

Comment: @logicOnAbstractions My link to extension fields documentation can be enough, the YAML feature is explained there

Comment: Is it possible to reuse extension fields for  substitution in `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: The extension fields work really well for reusing mappings, but unfortunately the merge key isn't supported for arrays. Does anyone know of a work around to use extension fields for arrays?

Comment: @colelemonz The best we can have is reusing values of specific keys: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27022292/4655476

Comment: @Wolphin is right! This is misleading and lead to more time than I would like wasting!!!!

Answer (score 47):

You can use the [extends](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#extends) directive (available in compose `1.x` and `2.x`) to have multiple containers inherit the `environment` configuration from an underlying service description.  For example, put the following in a file named `base.yml`:

```
version: '2'

services:
  base:
    environment:
      DB_URL: https://db:8443
      DB_USER_NAME: admin
      DB_USER_PASSWORD: admin
```

Then in your `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'

services:
  container1:
    image: alpine
    command: sh -c "env; sleep 900"
    extends:
      file: base.yml
      service: base

  container2:
    image: alpine
    command: sh -c "env; sleep 900"
    extends:
      file: base.yml
      service: base
    environment:
      ANOTHERVAR: this is a test
```

Then inside of `container1`, you will see:

```
DB_URL=https://db:8443
DB_USER_NAME=admin
DB_USER_PASSWORD=admin
```

And inside of `container2` you will see:

```
DB_URL=https://db:8443
DB_USER_NAME=admin
DB_USER_PASSWORD=admin
ANOTHERVAR=this is a test
```

You can obviously use `extends` for things other than the `environment` directive; it's a great way to avoid duplication when using docker-compose.

Comment: `extends` works well for my use case. It's preferable over local variables because it removes dependency on particular user. Another thing I can do with `extends` is to specify common container labels.

Comment: can I `extends` more than one service? or from more than one file per service?

Comment: For anyone else that is getting a FileNotFoundError when calling things from a subdirectory, you can use the relative path of the file instead: "./base.yml"

Comment: How do you do the `extends` notation if you want to extend from a service that is defined _in the same file_, not in a separate `base.yml` ?

Comment: You can't use `extends` for this, but maybe you can use [anchors and aliases](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/10-fragments/).

Answer (score 7):

You can reference local environment variables from within a docker-compose file. Assuming what you're wanting to do is make `USER_NAME` the same as `DB_USER_NAME`:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'

services:
  db:
    image: example/db
    ports:
      - "8443:8443" 
    container_name: db
    hostname: db
    environment:
      - USER_NAME = ${USERNAME}
      - USER_PASSWORD = ${PASSWORD}

svc:
  image: example/svc
  depends_on:
    - db
  ports:
    - "9443:9443"
  container_name: svc
  hostname: svc
  environment:
    - DB_URL = https://db:8443
    - DB_USER_NAME = ${USERNAME}
    - DB_USER_PASSWORD = ${PASSWORD}
```

Then, run docker-compose like:

```
$ USERNAME="admin" PASSWORD="admin" docker-compose up
```

Alternately, for something more permanent, and easier to type on a recurring basis:

```
$ printf '%s\n%s\n' 'export USERNAME="admin"' 'export PASSWORD="admin"' >> ~/.bash_profile
$ source ~/.bash_profile
$ docker-compose up
```

Comment: i think ```$ USERNAME="admin" PASSWORD="admin" docker-compose up``` is not good. hacker like ```$ history``` and get password with history cmd

Comment: @ChangwooRhee if you're using sensitive credentials for docker-compose locally you've got problems that are not technology-related

Comment: nothing wrong with local sensitive creds, in a non versioned file etc. But passing them as you do is worse, and an argument about something else being bad doesn't negate it's bad advice.

Comment: @James Perhaps I should have been more explicit: One should never have sensitive credentials locally. In fact, ideally, one should never have a human knowing the password to a production database.