# Pass same variables to multiple services in docker-compose without duplicating instructions?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have two services in my docker-compose file. Both of them need the same set of environment variables. Is there a better way to do this than duplicating instructions?

> PS: I have stored my variables in the "`.env`" file, which resides in the same directory as the docker-compose file.

**example docker-compose file:**

```
version: '3'

services: 
     service_1: 
           build: './s_1/'
           environment: 
                - variable_1 = ${variable_1}
                - variable_2 = ${variable_2}
                - variable_x = ${variable_y}
     service_2:
           build: './s_2/'
           environment: 
                - variable_1 = ${variable_1}
                - variable_2 = ${variable_2}
                - variable_x = ${variable_y}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Re-using environmental variables in docker-compose yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36283908/re-using-environmental-variables-in-docker-compose-yml)

Comment: @ŁukaszŚlusarczyk, wow. I spend 4 hours looking for an answer before I asked. How did I miss that. That's exactly what i wanted!