# bad parameter: Link is not supported podman docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, podman, wazuh

when try to run `docker-compose up` using **podman** i get this error **output**

> Creating single-node_wazuh.dashboard_1 ... error
> ERROR: for single-node_wazuh.dashboard_1  Cannot create container for service wazuh.dashboard: bad parameter: Link is not supported
> ERROR: for wazuh.dashboard  Cannot create container for service wazuh.dashboard: bad parameter: Link is not supported
> ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

**The compose File**

```yaml
# Wazuh App Copyright (C) 2017, Wazuh Inc. (License GPLv2)
version: '3.7'

services:
  wazuh.manager:
    image: wazuh/wazuh-manager:4.3.6
    hostname: wazuh.manager
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "1514:1514"
      - "1515:1515"
      - "514:514/udp"
      - "55000:55000"
    environment:
      - INDEXER_URL=https://wazuh.indexer:9200
      - INDEXER_USERNAME=admin
      - INDEXER_PASSWORD=SecretPassword
      - FILEBEAT_SSL_VERIFICATION_MODE=full
      - SSL_CERTIFICATE_AUTHORITIES=/etc/ssl/root-ca.pem
      - SSL_CERTIFICATE=/etc/ssl/filebeat.pem
      - SSL_KEY=/etc/ssl/filebeat.key
      - API_USERNAME=wazuh-wui
      - API_PASSWORD=MyS3cr37P450r.*-
    volumes:
      - wazuh_api_configuration:/var/ossec/api/configuration
      - wazuh_etc:/var/ossec/etc
      - wazuh_logs:/var/ossec/logs
      - wazuh_queue:/var/ossec/queue
      - wazuh_var_multigroups:/var/ossec/var/multigroups
      - wazuh_integrations:/var/ossec/integrations
      - wazuh_active_response:/var/ossec/active-response/bin
      - wazuh_agentless:/var/ossec/agentless
      - wazuh_wodles:/var/ossec/wodles
      - filebeat_etc:/etc/filebeat
      - filebeat_var:/var/lib/filebeat
      - ./config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/root-ca-manager.pem:/etc/ssl/root-ca.pem
      - ./config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/wazuh.manager.pem:/etc/ssl/filebeat.pem
      - ./config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/wazuh.manager-key.pem:/etc/ssl/filebeat.key
      - ./config/wazuh_cluster/wazuh_manager.conf:/wazuh-config-mount/etc/ossec.conf

  wazuh.indexer:
    image: wazuh/wazuh-indexer:4.3.6
    hostname: wazuh.indexer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    environment:
      - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - wazuh-indexer-data:/var/lib/wazuh-indexer
      - ./config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/root-ca.pem:/usr/share/wazuh-indexer/config/certs/root-ca.pem
      - ./config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/wazuh.indexer-key.pem:/usr/share/wazuh-indexer/config/certs/wazuh.indexer.key
      - ./config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/wazuh.indexer.pem:/usr/share/wazuh-indexer/config/certs/wazuh.indexer.pem
      - ./config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/admin.pem:/usr/share/wazuh-indexer/config/certs/admin.pem
      - ./config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/admin-key.pem:/usr/share/wazuh-indexer/config/certs/admin-key.pem
      - ./config/wazuh_indexer/wazuh.indexer.yml:/usr/share/wazuh-indexer/config/opensearch.yml
      - ./config/wazuh_indexer/internal_users.yml:/usr/share/wazuh-indexer/plugins/opensearch-security/securityconfig/internal_users.yml

  wazuh.dashboard:
    image: wazuh/wazuh-dashboard:4.3.6
    hostname: wazuh.dashboard
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 1234:5601
    environment:
      - INDEXER_USERNAME=admin
      - INDEXER_PASSWORD=SecretPassword
      - WAZUH_API_URL=https://wazuh.manager
      - API_USERNAME=wazuh-wui
      - API_PASSWORD=MyS3cr37P450r.*-
    volumes:
      - ./config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/wazuh.dashboard.pem:/usr/share/wazuh-dashboard/certs/wazuh-dashboard.pem
      - ./config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/wazuh.dashboard-key.pem:/usr/share/wazuh-dashboard/certs/wazuh-dashboard-key.pem
      - ./config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/root-ca.pem:/usr/share/wazuh-dashboard/certs/root-ca.pem
      - ./config/wazuh_dashboard/opensearch_dashboards.yml:/usr/share/wazuh-dashboard/config/opensearch_dashboards.yml
      - ./config/wazuh_dashboard/wazuh.yml:/usr/share/wazuh-dashboard/data/wazuh/config/wazuh.yml
    depends_on:
      - wazuh.indexer
    links:
      - wazuh.indexer:wazuh.indexer
      - wazuh.manager:wazuh.manager

volumes:
  wazuh_api_configuration:
  wazuh_etc:
  wazuh_logs:
  wazuh_queue:
  wazuh_var_multigroups:
  wazuh_integrations:
  wazuh_active_response:
  wazuh_agentless:
  wazuh_wodles:
  filebeat_etc:
  filebeat_var:
  wazuh-indexer-data:
```

for more check
https://github.com/wazuh/wazuh-docker

so how to avoid (use alternative/solution) "links" since it's [not supported](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/) by podman/docker (maybe in the futuer)?

Best Regards

Comment: Besides `links` being a legacy parameter, `docker-compose` and `podman` aren't really best friends in practice. If you like using `docker-compose` you may want to use `docker-ce` instead of `podman`.

Answer (score 3):

Links are a [legacy](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#links) option. If links are also used to share environment variables between containers, you can look at [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48651071/17650498).

I hope this helps you:

```
# Wazuh App Copyright (C) 2017, Wazuh Inc. (License GPLv2)
version: '3.7'

services:
  wazuh.manager:
    image: wazuh/wazuh-manager:4.3.6
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "1514:1514"
      - "1515:1515"
      - "514:514/udp"
      - "55000:55000"
    environment:
      - INDEXER_URL=https://wazuh.indexer:9200
      - INDEXER_USERNAME=admin
      - INDEXER_PASSWORD=SecretPassword
      - FILEBEAT_SSL_VERIFICATION_MODE=full
      - SSL_CERTIFICATE_AUTHORITIES=/etc/ssl/root-ca.pem
      - SSL_CERTIFICATE=/etc/ssl/filebeat.pem
      - SSL_KEY=/etc/ssl/filebeat.key
      - API_USERNAME=wazuh-wui
      - API_PASSWORD=MyS3cr37P450r.*-
    volumes:
      - wazuh_api_configuration:/var/ossec/api/configuration
      - wazuh_etc:/var/ossec/etc
      - wazuh_logs:/var/ossec/logs
      - wazuh_queue:/var/ossec/queue
      - wazuh_var_multigroups:/var/ossec/var/multigroups
      - wazuh_integrations:/var/ossec/integrations
      - wazuh_active_response:/var/ossec/active-response/bin
      - wazuh_agentless:/var/ossec/agentless
      - wazuh_wodles:/var/ossec/wodles
      - filebeat_etc:/etc/filebeat
      - filebeat_var:/var/lib/filebeat
      - ./config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/root-ca-manager.pem:/etc/ssl/root-ca.pem
      - ./config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/wazuh.manager.pem:/etc/ssl/filebeat.pem
      - ./config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/wazuh.manager-key.pem:/etc/ssl/filebeat.key
      - ./config/wazuh_cluster/wazuh_manager.conf:/wazuh-config-mount/etc/ossec.conf

  wazuh.indexer:
    image: wazuh/wazuh-indexer:4.3.6
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    environment:
      - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - wazuh-indexer-data:/var/lib/wazuh-indexer
      - ./config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/root-ca.pem:/usr/share/wazuh-indexer/config/certs/root-ca.pem
      - ./config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/wazuh.indexer-key.pem:/usr/share/wazuh-indexer/config/certs/wazuh.indexer.key
      - ./config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/wazuh.indexer.pem:/usr/share/wazuh-indexer/config/certs/wazuh.indexer.pem
      - ./config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/admin.pem:/usr/share/wazuh-indexer/config/certs/admin.pem
      - ./config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/admin-key.pem:/usr/share/wazuh-indexer/config/certs/admin-key.pem
      - ./config/wazuh_indexer/wazuh.indexer.yml:/usr/share/wazuh-indexer/config/opensearch.yml
      - ./config/wazuh_indexer/internal_users.yml:/usr/share/wazuh-indexer/plugins/opensearch-security/securityconfig/internal_users.yml

  wazuh.dashboard:
    image: wazuh/wazuh-dashboard:4.3.6
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 1234:5601
    environment:
      - INDEXER_USERNAME=admin
      - INDEXER_PASSWORD=SecretPassword
      - WAZUH_API_URL=https://wazuh.manager
      - API_USERNAME=wazuh-wui
      - API_PASSWORD=MyS3cr37P450r.*-
    volumes:
      - ./config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/wazuh.dashboard.pem:/usr/share/wazuh-dashboard/certs/wazuh-dashboard.pem
      - ./config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/wazuh.dashboard-key.pem:/usr/share/wazuh-dashboard/certs/wazuh-dashboard-key.pem
      - ./config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/root-ca.pem:/usr/share/wazuh-dashboard/certs/root-ca.pem
      - ./config/wazuh_dashboard/opensearch_dashboards.yml:/usr/share/wazuh-dashboard/config/opensearch_dashboards.yml
      - ./config/wazuh_dashboard/wazuh.yml:/usr/share/wazuh-dashboard/data/wazuh/config/wazuh.yml
    depends_on:
      - wazuh.indexer

volumes:
  wazuh_api_configuration:
  wazuh_etc:
  wazuh_logs:
  wazuh_queue:
  wazuh_var_multigroups:
  wazuh_integrations:
  wazuh_active_response:
  wazuh_agentless:
  wazuh_wodles:
  filebeat_etc:
  filebeat_var:
  wazuh-indexer-data:
```