# Docker: how to copy env var from 1 service to another

Tags: docker, docker-compose

here is the `docker-compose.yml` I would like to achieve:

```yaml
version: "3.4"

services:

  service1:
    image: dorowu/ubuntu-desktop-lxde-vnc

  service2:
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      - DISPLAY=[use env variable DISPLAY of service1]
```

Is there a way in docker compose to tell `service2` that the value of env variable `DISPLAY` must be the same as the env variable `DISPLAY` defined in `service1` ?

### Edit

The `DISPLAY` env var is set in `dorowu/ubuntu-desktop-lxde-vnc` directly in the Dockerfile.

It's not a duplicate of [Re-using environment variables in docker-compose.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36283908/re-using-environment-variables-in-docker-compose-yml) because the question asked how to write a common env variables for differents services.

In my case I don't want to explicitly write a common variables (with a `.env` file for example) but I want to set the env variable `DISPLAY` of service2 to the same value as `DISPLAY` in service 1 without having to rewrite it in a `.env` file.

For example if I wanted my service2 to have the same `DISPLAY` as my host I could write:

```yaml
version: "3.4"

services:

  service1:
    image: dorowu/ubuntu-desktop-lxde-vnc

  service2:
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      - DISPLAY=$DISPLAY
```

Now in this case I'm looking for something like:

```
version: "3.4"

services:

  service1:
    image: dorowu/ubuntu-desktop-lxde-vnc

  service2:
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      - DISPLAY=service1:$DISPLAY
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Re-using environment variables in docker-compose.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36283908/re-using-environment-variables-in-docker-compose-yml)

Comment: If `$DISPLAY` is X Window System configuration, and `service1` is running an X server and it's listening over TCP, you probably need to set this up like other cross-container communication: set `DISPLAY=service1:0.0`, which will most likely be a different value from the default in `service1` (probably `:0`).

Comment: @Anton, in fact I did not ask the same question. I edited the question to add more clarity.

Comment: @DavidMaze even though your solution might work, it's not what I'm looking for. I took this example but I could also take another env var as `SERVER_PORT` (or anything else). In fact I could make it work by setting `DISPLAY=:1.0` (in service2) and binding the volume `/tmp/.X11-unix` between the 2 services. Please read the edit for more clarity.

Comment: What sets `$DISPLAY` in `service1`?

Comment: @DavidMaze It's already set in the Dockerfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compose has no way of extracting information from an image and republishing it to another container.  You clarify that the environment variable is set in the first image's Dockerfile, and you want its value in the second container; there is no way to do that in Compose.

Of note, there's also no way to do this in plain Docker.  The closest you could come is launching a temporary container to get the environment variable out, but that's awkward

```bash
docker run \
  -e DISPLAY=$(docker run --rm dorowu/ubuntu-desktop-lxde-vnc sh -c 'echo $DISPLAY) \
  ...
```

A similarly awkward `docker inspect` invocation could retrieve the value.

But fundamentally, this capability isn't a standard part of the Docker tool set, and you can't do it at all in Compose (or other container environments like Kubernetes).

If you're setting the environment-variable value in Compose then there are tricks like YAML anchors and `env_file:` that can set the same value in multiple places (but not "share them from one container to another" *per se*).  You mention the X Window System `$DISPLAY` variable as an example, and for things that refer to other containers it's likely the server won't know its own name, so you'd need to set the environment variable directly in the client container in any case.

Answer (score 0):

ENV_FILE is what you need. You can share everything between apps by setting up variables in a common file.

```bash
# docker-compose.yml
build:
env_file: .env # here
```

#### .env

```bash
DISPLAY=env variable
```

Comment: Hello, yes I know but it's not what I'm looking for, the variable DISPLAY is already defined in `service1` by ther Dockerfile. I want to use it without having to write a `.env` file