# ruby YAML parser producing extraneous `<<` when aliasing array?

Tags: ruby, parsing, yaml

I would like to parse the YAML

```
foo: &foo
  - a: 1
bar: 
  <<: *foo
```

When I try to do this using ruby's YAML I get an odd result:

```
YAML.load("
foo: &foo
  - a: 1
bar: 
  <<: *foo
")

=> {"foo"=>[{"a"=>1}], "bar"=>{"<<"=>[{"a"=>1}]}}
```

Note the appearance of the odd `<<`.  I would have expected

```
   {"foo"=>[{"a"=>1}], "bar"=>[{"a"=>1}]}
```

Am I misunderstanding how to use the YAML syntax?

In case relevant:

```
ENV['RBENV_VERSION']
=> "2.4"
YAML.libyaml_version
=> [0, 1, 4]
```

I'm also a bit suspicious of my syntax because when I plug this into an [online yaml parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=foo%3A%20%26foo%0A%20%20foo2%3A%20%26foo2%0A%20%20%20%20-%20a%3A%201%0Abar%3A%20%0A%20%20%3C%3C%3A%20*foo%0Abaz%3A%20%0A%20%20%3C%3C%3A%20*foo2%0Aquux%3A%0A%20%20quux2%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%3C%3A%20*foo2&type=json) I get different output , but also different from what I expect:

```
{
  "foo": [{"a": 1}],
  "bar": {"a": 1}
}
```

(sorry, that's json -- but the point is that in the `bar` values is not wrapped in array brackets as I would expect.

Comment: It seems that in Ruby, only one part of merge key was implemented. Your second example is the correct one. That's what the merge key does, it results in a mapping, not a sequence of mappings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you cannot use arrays as top level keys when merging.
If you create a new rails app, you can see rails using this pattern inside **`config/database.yml`** (here's a snippet)

```
# config/database.yml

default: &default
  adapter: postgresql

development:
  <<: *default
```

In the example above it works fine, but see there's no array right below the **`default`** key.

In order for you code to work fine, you should wrap your array inside another key, like so:

```
# example.yml
foo: &foo
  list:
    - a: 1
bar:
  <<: *foo
```

And then you'll get:

```
YAML.load_file('example.yml')
#=> {"foo"=>{"list"=>[{"a"=>1}]}, "bar"=>{"list"=>[{"a"=>1}]}}
```

As you can see, the main problem is using arrays without wrapping them into a parent key.

Comment: Thanks!  Maybe the feature request to the YAML gem folks would be to reject the original syntax as a parse error rather than doing something weird...

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I found the answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4949139/239712 . Namely,

> ...it's not defined what the merge does. Per the [spec](http://yaml.org/type/merge.html), a merge key can have a value:
>
> - A mapping, in which case it's merged into the parent mapping.
> - A sequence of mappings, in which case each is merged, one-by-one, into the parent mapping.
>
> There's no way of merging sequences.