# In docker-compose, is it possible to reuse volume configuration between services?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

I'm trying using a setup similar to the following:

```
version: '3.4'
x-my-volumes: &volumes
    - '../src:/var/www/src/:cached'
    - '../static:/var/www/static/:cached'
services:
  webserver:
    build: ./.docker/webserver
    volumes:
      - *volumes
      - './serverlogs/:/var/www/serverlogs/:delegated'
  node:
    build: ./.docker/node
    volumes:
      - *volumes
```

I set up the "shared" volumes in the `x-my-volumes` section and give it an anchor of "volumes", which I try to utilise in my services. The main thing, though, is that the services have other volume mounts aside from the shared one. This doesn't work, with errors such as "`contains an invalid type, it should be an array`" when doing a `docker-compose up`.

Is this possible for docker-compose? I realise I can just copy and paste the volume mounts for each service in my real world scenario its 10+ services and 10+ volumes, so it's a lot of ugly duplication.

Answer (score 1):

If the volume array is exactly the same between services, you can do this:

```yaml
services:
  webserver:
    volumes: &volumes
      - one:one
      - two:two

  node:
    volumes: *volumes
```

If you wish to extend the array and add elements to it in some services, this does not seem to be supported in YAML as indicated by [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/yaml/yaml/issues/35) and [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948933/is-there-a-way-to-alias-anchor-an-array-in-yaml).

---

Perhaps to give you another approach to consider (although I am not sure it will be helpful for your use case):

In many of my docker compose, I define a "base" service, and then I can inherit some attributes of this service by other services, by using YAML merge. Consider this example:

```yaml
services:
  bash:
    build: .
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    <<: &default
      image: dannyben/borg-client
      volumes:
        - one:one
        - two:two

  init:
    <<: *default
    command: init -e repokey-blake2

  backup:
    <<: *default
    command: create --stats --progress ::initial-backup /borg/source
```

Using this approach I can have complex docker-compose files expressed in a very readable manner.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the case that merging sequences is unfortunately not currently possible in YAML. Thanks for the examples, though.